# How many additional crews should be brought in to minimize the cost of an oil spill?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

An oil spill has fouled $200$ miles of Pacific shoreline. The oil company responsible has been given $14$ days to clean up, after which a fine will be $10000$ \$/day. The local cleanup crew cleans $5$ miles/day at a cost of $500$ \$/day. Additional crews can be $18000$ dollars plus $800$ \$/day.

How many additional crews should be brought to minimize the total cost? How much is cost?

So far, I have the variables

- $t$ - time in days to clean up the oil spill
- $n$ - total crew
- $n_0$ - number of crew to clean up in exactly 14 days
- $p$ - the amount of fine in dollars
- $C$ - total cost in dollars
- $C$ =

I am not sure how to model the assumptions to minimize the cost or how to model the fine. Please help!

Comment: You might find this easier to start if you first concern yourself with how to model the cost (the work crews and the fine) before you give any thought to how to minimize anything. You should have a function whose input is $n$ and whose output is $C$. The function does not have to be expressed neatly in a single equation; you can have different equations for $n \leq 5$ and $n > 5$ (for example), or since this is an integer problem with (apparently) not too large values of $n$, even just a two-column table with values of $n$ in the left column and values of $C$ on the right if that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
  200 &= 5t + 5tn \\
  C &= \begin{cases}
        18000n + 800tn + 500t \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\mathrm{if}\quad t \leq 14 \\
        18000n + 800tn + 500t + 1000(t-14) \quad\quad\mathrm{if}\quad t > 14
      \end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Solve the first equation for $n$.
Substitute it into the second equation to get a piecewise function only in terms of $t$. 
Take the derivative of each piece $C(t)$ and find the zeros. 
If any those zeros are not integers, consider instead the integers on either side of that zero (we need a whole number of days). 
Plug these values (the zeros or their nearest integers) back into $C(t)$ to find the minimum. 
Use that $t$ in the first equation and solve for $n$.

Comment: I think the problem statement implies the fine is $1000(t-14)$ rather than $1000t$. Also, if on the last day you had $5n$ miles remaining to clean up, could you send one crew home and save $\$800$? (That's using your $n$, number of extra crews rather than OP's $n$ which was total number of crews.)

Comment: @DavidK, You're right that it should be $1000(t-14)$. That was an oversite on my part. It has been edited. As for sending a crew home, I didn't consider that at all.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I used 10000(t-14) although this doesn't affect the derivative.

Comment: Do either of you have a suggestion on a free program I could use to type this report up? @DavidK

Comment: @Brandon I can tell you about tools _I_ use: LaTeX (sometimes Microsoft Word if I am forced to) for large publication-ready documents, Microsoft Word, Open Office, or XHTML with MathJax for smaller documents. My guess is that Open Office would be your best bet, or maybe the free version of Word if supports the kinds of formulas you need to write. (The question is off-topic, but since we're already here ...)